# A palavra “estado” grafada com maiúscula inicial

Tags: ortografia, acordo-ortográfico, maiúsculas-e-minúsculas, escrita

Várias fontes afirmam que essa palavra deve ter sua primeira letra grafada em maiúscula quando faz referência a uma “nação politicamente organizada” (nas palavras do Manual de Comunicação da Secom, um dos primeiros portais que aparecem ao se pesquisar “estado em maiúsculas” no Google). Os dicionários Caldas Aulete, Priberam e Michaelis, os três disponíveis na internet, seguem a mesma lógica. A Real Academia Española, instituição oficial reguladora do espanhol, idioma familiar ao nosso, também a defende. Parece, em suma, haver um consenso em torno dessa posição quanto à palavra.

Entretanto, não consigo entender o porquê de tal posição. Alguns dizem que devemos usar a maiúscula para diferenciar um significado dos outros. Ora, se é assim, então por que não fazemos o mesmo com outras palavras? Não é possível que “estado” gere ambiguidade por não ter uma maiúscula no começo. Se não se trata de nome próprio, não há motivo para que a escrevamos com maiúscula inicial.

Aliás, sobre isso, vale lembrar que, na época do Formulário Ortográfico de 1943, havia regras no mínimo questionáveis no tocante às maiúsculas. Era dito que se empregava a maiúscula inicial “nos nomes que designam altos cargos, dignidades ou postos”, o que nos levava a ter de decidir o quão alto era um cargo. “Raça”, “pátria”, “nação” e assemelhados recebiam também o “privilégio” das maiúsculas. A meu ver, essa antiga regra parece ter influenciado a forma de escrevermos as palavras, porque, até hoje, é comum ler maiúsculas sem nenhuma justificativa, quase que como adornos ou servindo de negrito. No âmbito do direito, é um hábito comum. Há quem recomende que se escreva “Réu”, assim mesmo. Já li uma forma pior: “Estado Democrático de Direito”. Se “Estado” já é questionável, “Democrático de Direito” é uma aberração.

É mesmo só uma forma de enfeitar os textos? Discordam dessa visão? Por que inclusive as editoras seguem essa pseudoregra?

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se é assim tão questionável. O Estado é entidade sobre cuja autoridade e governo todos vivemos. Historicamente está por toda a parte, frequentmente é o maior empregador, tem o monopólio sobre a legítimidade da coerção, etc...Em última instância regula e arbitra qual o uso legítimo da linguagem.

> Não é possível que “estado” gere ambiguidade por não ter uma maiúscula no começo.

Por acaso, é diferente "o sistema do Estado" de "estado do sistema" de "sistema de estados", ou ainda "o Estado do sistema".

> na época do Formulário Ortográfico de 1943, havia regras no mínimo questionáveis no tocante às maiúsculas. Era dito que se empregava a maiúscula inicial “nos nomes que designam altos cargos, dignidades ou postos”

Os escribas realçam a sua posição realçando o sistema no qual têm posição. Qualquer agente social tenta o mesmo falando da organização à qual pertence, há organizações que arbitram o uso legítimo e censura da linguagem (e.g. é curioso como a gíria nos videos das prisões brasileiras soa hoje a mímica do [Pós-retomada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinema_do_Brasil#P%C3%B3s-retomada:_a_partir_de_2003). Como se a vida imitasse a arte, após a arte com todas as suas hipérboles ter imitado a vida - resultando todo o conjunto numa caricatura/imitação, um tanto acrítica senão anti-reflexiva). **EDIT**: O mesmo acontece quando oiço um político a repetir um falsa retórica despudorada.

> Alguns dizem que devemos usar a maiúscula para diferenciar um significado dos outros. Ora, se é assim, então por que não fazemos o mesmo com outras palavras?

Na língua Alemã todos os substantivos são escritos com maiúscula. O pronome pessoal "I" da 1ª pessoa do Inglês ser escrito com maiúscula e os restantes com minúscula, é mais um exemplo.

> até hoje, é comum ler maiúsculas sem nenhuma justificativa, quase que como adornos ou servindo de negrito. No âmbito do direito, é um hábito comum.

O direito é um campo próprio, provido das suas próprias lógicas internas. Vá-se lá tentar perceber aquele mundo, e aqueles agentes...

P.S. Deve ser pela mesma razão que escrevem:"É Noís" com maiúscula.

Answer (score 1):

Maiúscula ou Minúscula, conflito do revisor. Eu sou linguista e o que é da língua me interessa. Na minha visão, o uso de maiúscula é bastante flexível, mas não por "enfeite", pois refere-se principalmente a um substantivo próprio. Dizer que uma palavra é (ou não) substantivo próprio é desconsiderar que podemos usar um substantivo comum e usá-lo como próprio. Vai depender do destaque que se queira dar, singularizando o ser a que se pretende referir. É possível sim que Estado e estado podem gerar ambiguidade a depender de sua contextualização. Observo que se estabeleceu, quase como regra de uso, que Estado somente é grafado com inicial maiúscula remete à nação e os demais sentidos usam-se as iniciais minúsculas. Estado de espírito sim pode ser justificado com inicial minúscula, mas quando remetemos às Unidades da Federação, singularizando (ou seja, usando como substantivo próprio), deveria sim ser igualmente grafado com inicial maiúscula. Ora, mas as regras não são eternas, pois são alteradas conforme a recorrência de uso. Igualmente não há homogeneidade de uso, todas as áreas têm sua própria forma de dizer o mundo, e no Direito, há o costume de destacar, de singularizar o ser, logo é compreensível que façam largo uso da maiusculação.